# How do I remove comments of a file?

Tags: text-processing

I have an file (hosts.txt) and many lines in that file are comments. How do I remove that comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/^\#/d' myFile > tt
mv tt myFile
```

What happens here:

sed '/^#/d' myFile removes all lines starting with # from the file myFile and outputs the result in the console, > tt redirects the output into a temporary file called tt,
mv tt myFile moves the temporary file tt to myFile.

Comment: I would make the `mv` command conditional on `sed` completing successfully: `sed '/^\#/d' myFile > tt && mv tt myFile` -- or let sed handle the temp file: `sed -i '/^\#/d' myFile`

Comment: Yes you could do that , but it is unlikely to fail :)

Comment: Two commands for one simple task? And `\#` isn't necessary, `#` is enough.

Comment: @A.B. yes , that could be an optimization ^_^ . two commands to maintain simplicity

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sed](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/sed.1.html) Command and redirect the result to a new file by typing:

```
sed '/^\#/d' hosts.txt > cleaned.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-i` to edit files in place.

```
sed -i '/^#/d' hosts.txt
```

Or with a backup

```
sed -ibak '/^#/d' hosts.txt
```

---

from `man sed`

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
      edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
sed '/^#/ d' < inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc g/^#/d -cx hosts.txt
```

1. `g` global search
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close